# What is the correct viewing order for the Pokemon TV series and movies?

Tags: suggested-order, pokemon

There are a considerable number of Pokemon TV Series and movies. I am finding this most confusing.

**Can someone give me the correct viewing order?**

Answer (score 8):

The [attached link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_episodes) offers a complete viewing order for the pokemon TV series which is basically the original broadcast order. A complete list of the movies can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_films), again the movies are numbered for ease of reference.

As you can see, each set of movies corresponds to their appropriate season so (for example) the Season One movies are Pokémon:The First Movie, Pokemon 2, Pokemon 3, Pokemon 4ever and Pokémon Heroes. The Season 2 (Advanced Generation) movies are Jirachi Wish Maker, Destiny Deoxys, Lucario and the Mystery of Mew, Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea and so forth.

You should find it relatively easy to match them up (the exact episode order to films is [here](http://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?t=224542)) but don't worry as the movies are **purely supplementary, almost never referenced in the TV series and contain little to nothing in the way of spoilers.**

For my money, the essential TV season is [Season One : Indigo League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_episodes#Season_1:_Indigo_League). This series establishes many of the main characters you'll see throughout the next thousand episodes, notably our hero Ash and his friends and the primary antagonists in Team Rocket

Comment: Hmm. You know what they say about link-only answers :-) Maybe you should edit this to include an actual list? (I haven't looked into this in enough detail to know whether such a list would be possible or unfeasibly long; in the latter case, just tell me I'm being silly.)

Comment: @RandAl'Thor - I thought about it, but ultimately decided against it for several reasons; 1) The list is vast (600+ episodes) 2) The viewing order is basically the published order and 3) The wiki link seems pretty robust, with at least 800 redirects. It's not going anywhere.

Comment: In season one. There are a couple that were broadcast out of order. So if you watch on broadcast order you see some anomalies.